# Query Number of Followers of User Using Medium API

Tags: medium.com-publishing-api

I am trying to query the number of followers of a Medium user programmatically - but did not succeed yet.

Let me share all the things I tried, and if someone has any idea how to do it, I'd be grateful!

1. Analyze HTML page: one can simply download the html code of a profile page of a user and do some pattern matching to get the number of followers.
2. However, I'd like to query all the users of a publication and then get their follower numbers. For this, I found the [Medium API](https://github.com/Medium/medium-api-docs). Here, one can do a GET request `GET https://api.medium.com/v1/publications/{{publicationId}}/contributors` to get all users part of that publication. However, this only returns user IDs (not profile names / profile URLs), s.t. I don't know how to either a) connect this with 1 or b) follow up with the Medium API to query the number of followers of that user id.

As a final, general question I'd like to know if there's an official successor of this API - since the docs say it's deprecated - but no new one is linked. Any other options for APIs?

Thanks!

Described above. Tried methods 1 and 2.

Comment: Few months later, and I am facing the same issue as Im not able to find an alternative to the deprecated API, and they are not allowing any new integration with their API... Please share your feedback if you have found any replacement.

Comment: Unfortunately I did not follow this any further